# Sending a TCP message using PHP

Tags: php, laravel, sockets, tcp

I have an application that is listening on a port for TCP messages, and i need to write a PHP script that can send them.

This is what i am using for sending the TCP message but i dont know what is going wrong and i keep getting error 500. I am using Laravel.

```
public function tcp_msg(Request $request){

 $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);

    if ($socket === false) {
        $m1 = "Socket no creado";
        return $m1;
    }

    $msg = $request->Mensaje;
    $len = strlen($msg);

    $msg_error = 'Conexion no establecida';

    $conexion = socket_connect($socket, '127.0.0.1', 8688);

    if ($conexion === false) {
        $m2 = "No conectado";
        return $m2;
    }

    $resultado = socket_sendto($socket, $msg, $len, 0, '127.0.0.1', 8688);

    if($resultado){
        socket_close($socket);
        return $msg;
    }

    return $msg;

}
```

Comment: Is socket extension enabled? Check with `get_loaded_extensions()`

Answer (score 0):

This looks quite ok - usually you just need socket_create() and socket_sendto() to send a correct message.

You can remove the part with:

```
$msg_error = 'Conexion no establecida';

$conexion = socket_connect($socket, '127.0.0.1', 8688);

if ($conexion === false) {
    $m2 = "No conectado";
    return $m2;
}
```

Refering to https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-sendto.php

```
<?php
    $sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)

    $msg = "Ping !";
    $len = strlen($msg);

    socket_sendto($sock, $msg, $len, 0, '127.0.0.1', 1223);
    socket_close($sock);
?>
```

You may have to check if the listener to the port 8688 is working... socket_sendto() returns the number of bytes sent to the remote host, or FALSE if an error occurred.